# Cache Storage Management section is not displayed

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I need to refresh my cache. But when i go to cache management page. It doesn't showing the cache storage management section. That section is blank

[image: Check the screenshot here]

If someone faced these type of issue or anyone who know the reason for this , suggest me some idea

Comment: check var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log for errors, in the mean time you can use mage run to flush the cache, or do it manually.

Comment: This has either been manually removed in core code or something is crashing rendering of that grid resulting in no output being returned.